# Running jstack inside Docker container throws "Permission Denied"

Tags: java, docker, jvm, thread-dump, jstack

I am trying to get a thread dump of a Java service running inside Docker container. I got into the container terminal using the following command.

```
sudo docker exec -u 1000:0 -ti MyService /bin/bash
```

When I now run the following jstack command,

```
[ecs-user@myComputer /]$ jstack -l 436 > thread.dump
```

I get the following error.

```
bash: thread.dump: Permission denied
```

My docker container runAsUser is specified as `ecs-user` and that's the user the bash shell is running as. What permissions do I grant this user on which files to be able to do this thread dump? Or are there any other alternatives with jstack? Would appreciate any suggestions/advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with jstack.
The error says, `bash` can't create `thread.dump` file in the root directory. This is quite expected, since `/` is typically writable only by `root`. Try creating the output file in a different directory.

Comment: Oh that's stupid of me. It now says jstack not found. How can I install it on Docker?